# c++ program crashes linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
                if(tmpPtr->number<tmpPtr->next_number->number)
                {
                    int tmpV1=tmpPtr->next_number->number;
                    int tmpV2=tmpPtr->number;
                    tmpPtr->next_number->number=tmpV2;
                    tmpV2=tmpPtr->number=tmpV1;
                }
```

This is what I have tried so far, this is supposed to be sorting the linked list as member are being added each time. But when the compiler crashes when I try to put in the second node. The break point is the if statement, `if(tmpPtr->number<tmpPtr->next_number->number)`. I tried really hard to figure out what the problem was, but couldnt.

Comment: I'm guessing `tmpPtr->next_number` is `NULL` or uninitialized.

Comment: When using the debugger, which line caused the problem?

Comment: @DavidBrown I am guessing it is not properly linked. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the break point was `if(tmpPtr->number<tmpPtr->next_number->number)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that on the second run `tmpPtr` points to your first element which has a `next_number` value of `NULL`. So as soon as you try to dereference it, it will basically reduce itself to a `NULL` pointer which leads to a `SIGSEGV`.

after the first run

```
n->number = input
n->next_number = NULL
h = n
t = n
counter2 = 1
```

so starting with the second input

```
n->number
n->next_number = NULL
tmpPtr = h // which is the previous n and therefor h->next_number = NULL
tmpPtr->next_number == NULL // this is your problem since you do not check if next_number is a valid pointer
```

UPDATE:
if uploaded a (hackish) version of a solution at https://gist.github.com/sahne/c36e835e7c7dbb855076

Comment: you need to check if `tmpPtr->next_number` is not `NULL` before trying to access any of its elements.

Comment: btw. you also need to set `tmpPtr` to the next element within the loop or you will get a endless loop.

Comment: but isnt h pointing to the head of the list, i.e the first element? So how is it null in the first run?

Comment: `h->next_number` is `NULL` after the first run, since it points to the same memory as `n` and you set `n->next_number = NULL`

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, would you mind submitting the correct code?

Comment: so should I try to execute the loop after there are two elements added? I tried to do it though, but didnt work.

Comment: From what you said, I am guessing the if statement should execute after atleast there are 2 elements in the linked list, I think I fixed that but now it is an infinite loop as you mentioned, and now dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Oh ok, I see where the problem was. Thanx a looooooooot for the help and making this clear.

Answer (score 1):

for the second add, h->next_number is NULL, so on the first iteration of the inner while loop, you dereference NULL (alias of h->next_number->number).

**Edit**

When you're inserting the 2nd item:

head == tail, so head->next == NULL.

you start the inner loop:

head->number == first inserted item.

head->next == NULL.

head->next->number == dereferenced NULL.